# Запутался в приравнивании массивов и модуле copy

Tags: python, массивы, ссылки

Есть функция move(), которая должна повернуть массив против часовой стрелки на 90 градусов 0-3 раза, сделать с ним нужные вещи и повернуть ещё 1-3 раза, чтобы вернуть в изначальное положение. Функция берет массив из глобальной переменной с помощью deepcopy(), а потом возвращает изменённую версию.
У неё в помощниках функция rotation, которая принимает на вход массив, поворачивает на 90 градусов и возвращает.

```
def move(count_of_rotates):
    temporary_field = copy.deepcopy(field)
    # rotation
    for i in range(count_of_rotates):
        temporary_field = copy.deepcopy(rotation(temporary_field))
    # rotation back
    for i in range(4-count_of_rotates):
        temporary_field = copy.deepcopy(rotation(temporary_field))
    return temporary_field

def rotation(temporary_field):
    for i in range(len(field)):
        for j in range(len(field)):
            temporary_field[len(field)-1-j][i]=field[i][j]
    return temporary_field
```

Суть проблемы. Если во 2 строке функции move() стоит deepcopy(), то массив в итоге возвращается повернутым 1 раз. На скрине сверху массив до выполнения move(), снизу после, count_of_rorates=2.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вместо deepcopy() поставить просто =, то творится ахинея, вот пара примеров.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что интересно, при deepcopy() можно ещё хоть 100 раз поворачивать этот массив на 90 градусов, а во втором случае он один раз преобразовался и всё, дальше сколько не вводи в консоль, он будет оставаться таким же.

Перебрал весь гугл, не знаю, что делать. Решения по типу изменить логику не актуальны, так как пишу штуку для обучения, и надо разобраться в вопросе. Буду благодарен за ссылки, где понятно объясняют, когда питон создаёт ссылку на старый объект, когда создаёт новый объект, и как он это делает (можно на английском).

Answer (score 1):

Я понял, ошибка была в rotation(), я там постоянно запрашивал данные из field вместе temporary_field, и поэтому поворот каждый раз обнулялся. Но всё равно буду очень раз ссылкам по теме, неуверенно себя чувствую в копировании.